# angular foreach list element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a HTTP request set up than after all promises are met will return the scope. In this case its a list of products.

My goal is to set these products to have an opacity of 0 initially, and then with the foreach add a class which will give them an opacity of 1.

What I currently have works with the ul element, but I cannot get it to with the child elements.

This is currently in my promise:

```
angular.forEach(angular.element(document.querySelector('.product-list')), function(value, key){
    var a = angular.element(value);
    a.addClass("loaded");
});
```

But no amount of playing with .product-list li etc will work.

Any ideas?

Example of the HTML is:

```
<ul class="product-list">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
.product-list {
    li {
        opacity: 0;
        &.loaded {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And I will put a timeout in the foreach.

Comment: What's the relevant css and html?

Comment: @Starscream1984 Edited :)

Comment: Are you 100% sure that code is running? I think if you add a console.log(a) it won´t show

Answer (score 0):

I think your css (SASS? LESS?) should be:

```
.product-list {
    li {
        opacity: 0;            
    }

    &.loaded {
        li {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

as it looks like you are adding the `loaded` class to the `ul` element.